# "Extension of" or "Extension for"

Tags: expressions

Do we say extension of a period of time or extension for a period of time?

For example:

They requested an extension of a few days

Or

They requested an extension for a few days

I'm leaning more towards the former but I can't be sure. Thanks!

Comment: I think you mean "an extension".

Comment: And with that correction they mean slightly different things.  In the first case "a few days" is added to the deadline.  In the second case the deadline is moved to "a few days" from the present time.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry for the typo. Thank you!